# Python - Removing item from dictionary if first tuple key not in other dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have two dictionaries `D1`, `D2`. `D1` contains a key followed by a value. `D2` contains a tuple as the key followed by a value.

```
D1 = {'x':123, 'x1': 154, 'x2':184}

D2 = {('x','x1'):50, ('x1','x2'):30, ('y','x2'):10}
```

Is there a way to remove an item from `D2` if the first part of the tuple-key is not a key in `D1`? So in this example, the item in `D2` that has 'y' as the first tuple-key value should be removed from the dictionary. So `D2` would then look like this.

```
D2 = {('x','x1'):50, ('x1','x2'):30}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try iterating over D2.items():

```
D1 = {'x':123, 'x1': 154, 'x2':184}
D2 = {('x','x1'):50, ('x1','x2'):30, ('y','x2'):10}
new_dict = {i:j for i,j in D2.items() if i[0] in D1}
print(new_dict)
```

**Output**

```
{('x', 'x1'): 50, ('x1', 'x2'): 30}
```

Comment: You don't need to use `dict.keys()`, instead you can simplify to `{k: v for k, v in D2.items() if k[0] in D1}`

Answer (score 1):

Make a copy of `D2` using `.copy()` and iterate over it to avoid mutating the original dict and getting `RuntimeError` while doing `.pop()`

```
D1 = {'x':123, 'x1': 154, 'x2':184}
D2 = {('x','x1'):50, ('x1','x2'):30, ('y','x2'):10}

for i in D2.copy():
    if i[0] not in D1.keys():
        D2.pop(i)
```

D2 Becomes:

> {('x', 'x1'): 50, ('x1', 'x2'): 30}

Answer (score 0):

Simple function to do this:

```
D1 = {'x':123, 'x1': 154, 'x2':184}

D2 = {('x','x1'):50, ('x1','x2'):30, ('y','x2'):10}

def remove_keys(d1, d2):
    keys_list = d1.keys()
    keys_to_remove = []
    for k1, k2 in d2.keys():
        if k1 not in keys_list:
            keys_to_remove.append((k1, k2))
    for key in keys_to_remove:
        del d2[key]
    return d2


D2 = remove_keys(D1, D2)
```